# An integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $f(a)=0$. Prove:
\begin{gather}
\int_a^b f^2(x) dx \le (b-a)^2 \int_a^b (f'(x))^2 dx
\end{gather}

Taylor's Theorem seems like the obvious solution route, but nothing I try will get me all the way there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Cauchy Schwarz inequality:
$$
f(x)^2 = \left(\int _a^x f'(x) dx \right)^2 \le (x-a)\int _a^x f'(x)^2 dx
 \le (b-a)\int _a^b f'(x)^2 dx 
$$

and now integrate once again.

Comment: I think this should be solvable with real analysis machinery.

Comment: @user194089 you are right.

Comment: Alright I see, thanks a bunch mate.